# What event is fired when Mac is locked / woke up?

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to get a notification in my app whenever the Mac is getting locked or woke up.

I lock it programmatically using requesting idle with `IORequestIdle`.

In my AppDelegate, I added this function to track NSNotifcation :

```
NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sleepListener(aNotification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSWorkspaceWillSleep, object: nil)

NSWorkspace.shared().notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(sleepListener(aNotification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.NSWorkspaceDidWake, object: nil)

func sleepListener(aNotification : NSNotification) {

        print("Received notification")

        if aNotification.name == NSNotification.Name.NSWorkspaceWillSleep {
            print("Going to sleep")
        } else if aNotification.name == NSNotification.Name.NSWorkspaceDidWake {
            print("Woke up")
        } else {
            print("Some other event other than the first two")
        }
    }
```

but the `sleepListener` function never gets called.

Comment: Isn't it `NSNotification.Name.willSleepNotification` and `NSNotification.Name.didWakeNotification`?

Comment: @vadian I think that's Swift 4, I'm still on Swift 3 :)

Comment: Try `#selector(sleepListener(_:))` and `func sleepListener(_ aNotification : NSNotification) {`